# Open an app in low resolution but not zoomed

Tags: macos, display, resolution

Can I open an application on a retina display tricking it that it's actually using a low resolution display, but not doubling the pixels? Yes, I want tiny text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open a single app in low resolution unscaled, but you can set the display to a non-HiDPI resolution such as 2880×1800 using an app such as [RDM](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/vi9yf/set_your_retina_macbook_pros_resolution_to/%5C).